# SQL Query Difference between Table 1 compared to Sum of Table2 Child Items Referenced by Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say I have 2 tables:

**Table1**

```
 ID    Name    Quantity
 1     Pencil        12
 2     Pen           35
 3     Ruler         50
```

**Table 2**

```
 ID    Name    Quantity   FK_Table1
 1     Pencil         6           1
 2     Pencil         6           1
 3     Pen           10           2
 4     Pen            5           2
 5     Pen            5           2
 6     Pen            5           2
 7     Ruler         12           3
 8     Ruler         12           3
 9     Ruler         12           3
10     Ruler         12           3
```

- I need to make a query that selects only the row in table1 from quantity column where it doesn't match with the sum of all quantity column in Table2 that are having the same FK_Table1 value

  (e.g. Pencil will not be selected since its quantity is 12 in table1, the same as the sum of quantities of row ID# 1 and 2 in table2).
- I need to make a query that selects the table2 rows instead of table1, but with same rules applied

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried to do (pls post your query script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query :

```
select * from table1 t1
where t1.Quantity <> (select sum(t2.Quantity) from table2 t2 where t2.FK_Table1 = t1.ID);
```

For getting records of Table 2:

```
select * from table2 where FK_Table1 IN(
  select t1.ID from table1 t1
  where t1.Quantity <> (
    select sum(t2.Quantity) from table2 t2 where t2.FK_Table1 = t1.ID
   )
);
```

Comment: Then there will be multiple rows for same item. You want that ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but what I'm trying to achieve is to show table2, rows with ID 3-10 should be returned in SELECT statement since they do not match the parent's quantity if you sum those child items having the same foreign keys

Comment: @KaySingian: Please see the updated answer. Also request you to please select answer as correct answer to your question if this works fine for you.